# Helm deploy does not update/remove code that was changed prior on Cronjobs or Deployments

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am new to the K8s realm but enjoy this service. I do have two issues which I was expecting Helm to be able to update.

For instance, my question revolves around when I do a `helm upgrade`. Let's say I have code where I have a `volumeMount` of a directory in `Deployments` or `Cronjobs`. Whenever I do the update in my YAML file to **remove the mount**, it still exists after Helm's completion.

So what I do is edit the YAML file of let's say `deployment.yaml` or `cronjobs.yaml` in the CLI k8s (I use k9s) for `deployment.yaml`. However, `cronjobs.yaml` is the hard one since I have to delete it and run `helm update` again. (Please let me know if there is a way of updating `Cronjobs` a better way because if I update `Deployments` the pods are updated but with `Cronjobs` they don't.)

Would appreciate any help with my questions on how best to work with k8s.